# Making Unity shadows work at a small scale

Tags: unity, shadows, shadow-mapping

I'm trying to cast shadows from a small (3cm) sphere onto a table surface.

If I place a large object, I get shadows as expected, but below a certain size, I get nothing.

[image]

I appreciate that under normal circumstances, shadow map resolution wouldn't allow this level of detail, however, my entire scene is 2x2x3 metres.

I could scale up everything to work around the issue, but that would cause a lot of knock-on issues when it comes to physics, VR and a whole slew of other things.

How can I take the shadowmap area Unity would usually assign to a whole scene and apply it to a single tabletop?

[image]

I've tried tweaking the `Lightmapping` properties for the table, but haven't seen any visible difference.

Edit: Changing clipping planes didn't have any obvious impact (different angle as from the camera, not editor view)

[image]

Comment: Do you find any impact from tightening the near & far planes on your camera? By default it's set to see thousands of meters, which signals to Unity that you need your shadow maps to cover a huge area, leaving few pixels per cm. Shrinking down the size might help it cluster those pixels where you need them. Shadow maps don't use your lightmapping settings.

Comment: @DMGregory, Unfortunately not, no visible difference reducing both by a factor of 10 or 100 (screenshot edited into Q). If shadowmaps don't use lightmap settings, how can I control the shadow map for an object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@DMGregory's suggestion was enough to point me in the right direction...

[image]

Changing the camera clipping plane didn't help, however, changing the max shadow distance worked.

[image]